# New to JS and testing - trying to get the selector for this code (TestCafe)

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cucumber, testcafe

Not sure how to get the selector from this code. On the web app it's displayed as a button that has a dropdown after clicked. Trying to create a test step where this button is clicked, but I can't seem to find/create the right selector.

```
import { ChevronDownIcon } from '/icons';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import UserAvailabilityBadgeIcon from '/components/UserAvailabilityBadgeIcon';

const UserLabel = ({ userName }) -> {
    return (
        <>
            <UserAvailabilityBadgeIcon />
            <span>{userName}</span>
            <ChevronDownIcon />
    );
};

UserLabel.propTypes = {
    userName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default UserLabel;
```

Keep getting the error code E24 from TestCafe which is element not found

Comment: This information is not sufficient to reproduce the issue. Please create a separate ticket in the official GitHub repository using the following [bug template](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml) so that the TestCafe team can research the problem. Please also refer to the following help topic: [how to create a minimal working example](https://testcafe.io/402636/faq#how-to-create-a-minimal-working-example-when-you-submit-an-issue).

Answer (score 0):

The [Visual Selector Debugger](https://testcafe.io/documentation/404288/guides/intermediate-guides/visual-selector-debugger) is available in TestCafe@2.4.0. In particular, it can generate selectors for the selected element:
[image]

I think this item will be useful to you.